# Non-raised tildes in a minted environment

Tags: beamer, minted

Consider the following minimal example that combines Beamer + Minted:

```
\documentclass[11pt,utf8]{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Foobar}
\begin{minted}{ocaml}
let foobar ~x ~y = x + y
\end{minted}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the tilde characters in function `foobar` inside the minted environment are rendered almost as superscripts.  I want them to be rendered as is customary in monospaced fonts: vertically centered.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a font issue.  Try `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` plus
`\usepackage{lmodern}`, or something similar.

[image: fixed tilde]

Answer (score 2):

I had issue with tilde also after specifying font to `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{lmodern}`. I solved problem by setting:

> \setminted[r]{fontfamily=courier}
>
> % or equvalently
>
> \mint[fontfamily=courier]{r}|lm(y~x)|

Answer (score 0):

I combined the other two answers and solved the problem by setting:

```
\setminted[]{fontfamily=lmtt}
```

This way the font Latin Modern Sans Typewriter is set only to the minted environment, to all code snippets written in all languages.